# A/D converter quantization noise

Tags: dsp-core, quantization, analog-to-digital

I read that in A/D converter we usually use rounding or two's complement truncation and not the sign magnitude or 1's complement truncation as in this case the quantization error is correlated to the input signal.
Can some one with A/D quatization knowledge alabaret this for me.
Is the quantization error in two's complement truncation between(-delta,+delta) or is it (-delta,0), with delta being the quatization error.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The quantization *noise* is always correlated to the input signal. What do you mean by correlation of the quantization *error* to the input? And could you elaborate on 2's and 1's complement truncation? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: try http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/39-06/Chapter%202%20Sampled%20Data%20Systems%20F.pdf, page 37 and further. This book has exhaustive materials about data converters

Comment: Actually I think the two's complement and 1's complement truncation are different based on the fact that when we quantize our data,it really deponds where we put our comparators.and the problem is that I dont understand why in the case of first complement truncation the noise and signal are correlated to each other but notin 2's complement form.I dont know more than this I am trying to find out.